# is it good to use following in react hooks or any alternative to update the UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

here is my code i am facing the issue that the UI not reRendering after the state changes

```
const [, setRand] = useState()
setRand(Math.random())
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? Where are you using the random number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use `useState` as `const [, setRand] = useState()`;

Here is the description from [ReactJs documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

You need to use it like this

```
const [random, setRandom] = useState(0);
//or you can just set random in the beginning like
const [random, setRandom] = useState(Math.random());
```

And make sure you are accessing it somewhere on `return()` method like:

```
<p>{ random }</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use **key** attribute for re-rendering

```js
return (
  <SomeOtherComponent>
    <Component key={dependencyVariable} />
  </SomeOtherComponent>
)
```